# python script executes differently when exec()'ed from PHP

Tags: python, mysql-connector, raspberry-pi4

On a Raspberry 4, I have a simple python script `bb_refresh_sensors_from_php.py` which executed flawlessly from my (Thonny) IDE.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#import sys
from bb_sensors_on_bus import SensorsOnBus
from python_database.sensor import Sensor
from bb_configuration import DEBUG

bDebug = DEBUG['bb_refresh_sensors_from_php']

SensorsOnBus.Initialize()
    
# 1. Scan files for current thermometer sensors; obtain array of dictionaries {serial_number, temp_measured, status}:
arr_dict_ds18b20 = SensorsOnBus.Scan()
if bDebug:
    # create dictionary item:
    debug_item = dict(ds18b20_serial_number = "refresh sensor 02", temp_measured = 17.0, status = "DEBUG REFRESH SENSORS")
    arr_dict_ds18b20.append(debug_item)

# 2. If sensor if not already in the sensor table, insert it:
for dict_ds18b20 in arr_dict_ds18b20:
    ds18b20_serial_number = dict_ds18b20['ds18b20_serial_number']
    sensor = Sensor([ds18b20_serial_number], ['ds18b20_serial_number'])
    sensor.insert() 
    
print ("Number of sensors found on bus: "+str(len(arr_dict_ds18b20)))
```

However, the purpose of this script is to be called from PHP:

```
$number_of_sensors_on_bus = exec("/home/wp/PythonCode/bb_refresh_sensors_from_php.py 2>&1");
```

This same script crashes when exec()'ed from PHP with the following error message (obtained by PHP's `passthru()`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wp/PythonCode/bb_refresh_sensors_from_php.py", line 4, in <module>
    from python_database.sensor import Sensor
  File "/home/wp/PythonCode/python_database/sensor.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .databaseobject import Databaseobject
  File "/home/wp/PythonCode/python_database/databaseobject.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .databaseconnection import DatabaseConnection
  File "/home/wp/PythonCode/python_database/databaseconnection.py", line 4, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

When I go to CLI on my Raspberry, and I execute `pip show mysql-connector-python`, I get:

```
Name: mysql-connector-python
Version: 8.2.0
Summary: MySQL driver written in Python
...
```

To make this more mysterious, I ask the Python version with this simple script:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

When run from the IDE, I obtain:

```
3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
```

But when passthru()'ed from PHP, I get the following message (which suggests to me that the python interpreter is not even started):

```
/home/wp/PythonCode/240106_version.py: 1: import: not found
/home/wp/PythonCode/240106_version.py: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

(Edit: This has been resolved by @erik258's comment)

I am expecting the script to run identically, both from my IDE and when called from PHP.

[Oddly enough, I have another (more complex) python script (which does not use the mysql-connector) which DOES run identically, from the IDE and when called from PHP.]

Edit: @erik258: Both from the CLI and from PHP exec(), `which pip` returns: `/usr/bin/pip`

I also ran the `pip --version` command from CLI and PHP exec. Both return the same:

```
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Comment: "To make this more mysterious... " that's an easy mystery to solve.  Your short version script doesn't start with "#!/usr/bin/env python3", so it's being interpreted with a shell, probably `/bin/sh`.

Comment: "This same script crashes when exec()'ed from PHP" PHP's python runtime is different from your user's.  You might have installed those packages locally to your user, or even be running in a python virtualenv.  What is `which pip` from your Raspberry CLI that shows `mysql-connector-python` being installed?  And what is `which pip` from the PHP exec?